# Salesforce XML to Gzip compressed file

Tags: apex

is there any native Salesforce Solutions available to convert a xml file as gzip compressed file?

We are trying to integrate with a 3rd party , which accepts a gzip compressed xml file and then converted into base64 format in their request body.

Answer (score 0):

The `setCompressed()` method of the `HttpRequest` class appears to do just that (apply gzip compression to the request body).

From the [documentation on HttpRequest](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm)

> setCompressed(flag)
>   If true, the data in the body is delivered to the endpoint in the gzip compressed format. If false, no compression format is used.